# StencilJS : How to debounce listeners

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I want to debounce the following listener:

```
  @Listen('mousemove')
  mouseMove(event) {
    ...
  }
```

I haven't found a way to do it in the documentation, any thought ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can does debounce in your own way.

```
class MyComponent {
  private debounce: ?number = null;

  @Listen('mousemove')
  mouseMove(event) {
    if (this.debounce !== null) {
      clearTimeout(this.debounce);
      this.debounce = null;
    }

    this.debounce = window.setTimeout(() => {
      // your debounced traitment
      
      this.debounce = null;
    }, 200);
  }
}
```

Goal here is to use a flag `debounce` to keep a reference of your debounced traitment.

Because your `mouseMove` method will be called multiple time, it will cancel the previous stacked timeout until `mouseMove` are not called for at least `200ms`.

Then your callback inside your timeout will be runned.

Answer (score 1):

Stencil doesn't include a debounce feature as far as I'm aware.

I usually use the [throttle-debounce](https://github.com/niksy/throttle-debounce) package and listen for the event myself, without the `@Listen` decorator:

```
connectedCallback() {
  this.debouncedResize = debounce(200, false, () => {
    this.onResize();
  });
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.debouncedResize);
}

disconnectedCallback() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.debouncedResize);
}

onResize() {
  // do some work
}
```

Don't forget to remove the event when you don't need it anymore.